# How to find out if a Lucene query has at least one result efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I need to find out if my BooleanQuery has at least one matching document. I don't care about the total number of matching documents -- only that there is at least one match. Currently I'm using `IndexSearcher.Search(...)` with `n = 1`, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way.

If I set `n = 1`, `TotalHits` will still be set to the correct value (i.e. it may be higher than 1), so I'm suspecting that Lucene does extra work that I don't need.

Is there a better way of doing this?

P.S. I'm using Lucene .NET 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene doesn't search through each document to determine the number of hits. It searches through the index, which refers back to the matching documents. Think about a book's index:

```
Cats . . . . . 5, 8, 9, 10
Dogs . . . . . 5, 6, 11, 12
Horses . . . . 5, 8, 12, 13, 14
```

If I'm searching for "Cats AND Horses", there isn't really a significant difference in the amount of work required to tell me "1 or more hits" vs "2 hits".

---

As far as short circuiting in a boolean query full of "should" clauses, I'm not aware of any query class that does this. If you have a query like `field:simpleterm field:*slowwildcardquery*`, and don't want to evaluate the big slow wildcard query if there is a match on the simple term query, you should just run them as separate searches. If the first doesn't return any hits, then run the second.

Comment: thanks for clarifying! i shall stick with my original query then :)